# How to group object key by value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an object with this structure `{aaas:"good","aasda":"ok","adasa":"good","ascas":"good","asdasd":"nw","asdasda":"nw",asdqw:"nw","assa":"ok","asscsa":"ok"}`

Here I want to group each key with the similar value and put these to new object.
Just like `newObj={"aaas":"good","adasa":"good","ascas":"good"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object and group by value.

```js
var object = { aaas: "good", aasda: "ok", adasa: "good", ascas: "good", asdasd: "nw", asdasda: "nw", asdqw: "nw", assa: "ok", asscsa: "ok" },
    grouped = {};

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    if (!grouped[object[k]]) {
        grouped[object[k]] = {};
    }
    grouped[object[k]][k] = object[k];
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
    var obj = {'aaas':"good","aasda":"ok","adasa":"good","ascas":"good","asdasd":"nw","asdasda":"nw",asdqw:"nw","assa":"ok","asscsa":"ok"};
    var newObj={};
    angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
    if(value=="good"){
    newObj[key]=value;
    }
    });
```

Hopes this helps you .. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much @Ujjwal kaushik

Answer (score 1):

The object needs a little work (yours was missing quotes):

```
const data = {
  "aaas":"good",
  "aasda":"ok",
  "adasa":"good",
  "ascas":"good",
  "asdasd":"nw",
  "asdasda":"nw",
  "asdqw":"nw",
  "assa":"ok",
  "asscsa":"ok"
};

groupUp = (input) => {
  return input.reduce(arr, (key, val) => {
    if (!_.includes(arr, key)) {
      arr.push(_.groupBy(input, key));
    }
    return arr;
  }, []);
}

console.log(groupUp(data));
```

That should get what you want (I haven't tested it though, and it uses lodash methods, so you might want to slightly rewrite that if you don't use lodash).

Comment: Thanks @rrd for your help.